# Elastic Search Partial Update with Hibernate Search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, hibernate-search, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to execute partial updates in Elastic Search using Hibernate Search. I have checked the requests to Elastic Search created by Hibernate Search and they update the whole document.

I need this requirement because my documents contain a field with the contents of a file, this field is only filled in the creation of the document and it never changes. Extracting the content of the file is quite expensive because requires some decryption and processing by Apache Tika. On the other hand, the other fields change very often.

```
Attachment (class) 
    Name (field)  
    Content (field) - it never changes and expensive to extract        
    Folder (field) - it changes very often
    Status (field) - it changes very often
```

Is it possible to execute Elastic Search partial updates with Hibernate Search or there is any other way of solving this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to solve your efficiency problem with the current version of Hibernate Search. Partial updates would be a solution, but they are not implemented yet. I added [a ticket on the JIRA instance](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2888) so that we add the feature it in a future version. Feel free to vote for it or provide additional insight.

Comment: One potential solution may be to keep the extra Tika-processed field in another index which is driven by a secondary table for your entity (not sure whether that's supported by Hibernate Search, but @YoannRodière may know more).

Comment: @Gunnar That would solve the efficiency problem, but would only be practical if one doesn't need to filter on both the tika and non-tika fields in the same query, because there's no join feature (yet) either.